# Custom Popup Dialogs

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm looking into implementing custom popup dialogs as seen in the picture below, and have come across various approaches to achieve this goal.

1- Calling a `View` that is positioned outside of the screen which adds an overlay to the current view hierarchy and animates its way to the center of the screen

2- Using UIPresentationController which requires tons of code

3- Using a pod

I'd like to know what is the current state of such 'popups in iOS, and which are the simplest and most straightforward to implement.

I'm looking for an answer that exhaustively compares the existing options and clearly demonstrates the pros and cons of each.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are supporting iOS 8 and upwards (which you should be, where possible!) I would recommend using a UIViewController with a UIPresentationController to handle the curtain view in the background.

My reasons:

• These are both pretty new, 100% native APIs.

• Apple has made interesting changes to some of their own APIs (see UIAlertController) where they have transitioned from UIView/UIControls to UIViewControllers.

I should note that a UIViewController could be overkill here as I get the impression the popover would be pretty simple. Still, it's also pretty simple to implement.

Here's some sample code of the UIViewController I'm presenting:

The SecondViewController is the popover:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "SecondPresentationController.h"

@interface SecondViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic, getter=isPresenting) BOOL presenting;

@end


@implementation SecondViewController

#pragma mark - Initialization

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        self.transitioningDelegate = self;
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
        self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Content Size

- (CGSize)preferredContentSize {

    return CGSizeMake(266.0f, 143.0f); // The static size of the test image I'm using for this sample code.
}


#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    return 1.0;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {

    self.presenting = YES; /// Used in animateTransition

    return self;
}


- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {

    self.presenting = NO; /// Used in animateTransition

    return self;
}


- (UIPresentationController *)presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceViewController:(UIViewController *)source {

    return [[SecondPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:self presentingViewController:self.presentingViewController];
}


#pragma mark - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];

    CGSize preferredSize = toViewController.preferredContentSize;

    // onscreenFrame will be in the center of the superview, while offscreen will be just below the superview (and off of the screen completely)

    CGRect onscreenFrame = CGRectMake((fromViewController.view.bounds.size.width - preferredSize.width) * 0.5f, (fromViewController.view.bounds.size.height - preferredSize.height) * 0.5f,
                                      preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

    CGRect offscreenFrame = onscreenFrame;

    offscreenFrame.origin.y = fromViewController.view.bounds.size.height;

    // Set the *initial* frame for the viewController.

    if (self.isPresenting) {

        toViewController.view.frame = offscreenFrame;
    }
    else {

        toViewController.view.frame = onscreenFrame;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.8f initialSpringVelocity:0.8f options:kNilOptions animations:^{

        // Now animate to the final frame.
        if (self.isPresenting) {

            toViewController.view.frame = onscreenFrame;
        }
        else {

            toViewController.view.frame = offscreenFrame;
        }


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];


}

@end
```

The SecondPresentationController handles the curtainview:

```
#import "SecondPresentationController.h"

@interface SecondPresentationController ()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *curtainView;

@end


@implementation SecondPresentationController

- (instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController {

    self = [super initWithPresentedViewController:presentedViewController presentingViewController:presentingViewController];

    if (self) {

        _curtainView = [UIView new];
        self.curtainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f];
        self.curtainView.alpha = 0.0f;

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)presentationTransitionWillBegin {

    UIView *containerView = self.containerView;

    self.curtainView.frame = containerView.bounds;

    self.curtainView.alpha = 0.0f;

    [containerView insertSubview:self.curtainView atIndex:0];

    [self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

        self.curtainView.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:nil];
}


@end
```

Then, you would present the SecondViewController as normal.

The result:

[image: The result after presenting the popup.]
It's certainly a bit more complicated than a UIView but there's no need to mess with the app's UIWindow, or ask the UIWindow's RootViewController to add our popover as a subview. If you have any questions, please let me know.